# Fail to deploy node on Elastic Beanstalk : The command '/bin/sh -c npm install' returned a non-zero code: 1

Tags: reactjs, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am using elastic beanstalk from AWS to deploy and host a react application using Docker.

The deployment fails mysteriously, even though I succeed building the Docker image on my local machine.
An inspection to the logs on the EC2 instance (using `eb ssh`) does not provide more explanation that this:

```
--------------------------------
/var/log/eb-commandprocessor.log
--------------------------------
Step 5/14 : COPY package.json /usr/src/app/package.json
---> Using cache
---> f06f2c9d6519
Step 6/14 : RUN npm install
---> Running in 9926fc11431f
The command '/bin/sh -c npm install' returned a non-zero code: 1
Failed to build Docker image aws_beanstalk/staging-app: 2c9d6519
```

I even tried to run the `npm install` command inside the last layer of the built container using

```
sudo docker commit 9926fc11431f test && docker run -it test bash
cd /path/to/wordir
npm install
```

But the return code is actually 0

Is there any other way this could fail and logs return me wrong errors ?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I'm getting the same issue and can't figure out a solutoin

Comment: I've never solved this. I ended up using the kubernetes engine instead of beanstalk and building my images separatly.
Another solution is to store the dependencies in the repository so you can skip the npm install within the image (but I don't know if this considered a good practice)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm writing this answer for any future people which come by this. **If there is no NPM error message**. The issue is *memory exhaustion* there are two ways to resolve this on Beanstalk specifically:

- Use a machine with more memory (instead of say a t2.micro)
- (recommended) Switch to `yarn`. Yarn uses much less memory than npm.
- Figure out some other way to reduce your memory footprint

This issue gave me a lot of headache so I hope this helps future folks who come across this issue.